# Odd use of False constant in if-then statement

Tags: perl

Python is my main language, but have to maintain a rather large legacy Perl codebase.
I have an odd logic statement that I can't make heads or tails over.

At top, a constant is defined as:

```
use constant FALSE => 0;

sub thisFunc {

    FALSE if ($self->{_thisVar} ne "tif");

    ...
    ...
    return statement,etc..
}
```

So I'm reading that as a kinda' fancy, non-standard if-then statement,
that if $thisVar string is not equal to "tif", then FALSE.  Huh? 
Not something like $that = FALSE, just *FALSE*.

The form of this statement appears in the file several times.
This codebase is in use, and vetted over the years by very good team,
so I think it is valid and has meaning. "use strict;" is set at top.

Could someone be so kind as to explain what is meant by logic. 
I've Google'd it but no joy.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: That `FALSE if ...` line looks completely pointless to me.  (That is, it performs no useful function, and may as well be omitted.)  Seeing the real code would be helpful; perhaps you've inadvertently omitted something important.

Comment: Maybe it was supposed to say `return FALSE if....`.

Comment: @AndyLester, also, if that function perhaps used to consist of that one line, and somebody messed up in expanding it, that would be an equivalent case.

Comment: what follows the FALSE if?  is it at the end of the sub or a do or eval block that could be receiving the value?

Comment: There is code that follows these one-liners, but it doesn't relate directly or code-logically.  Since many (all?) of the perl files have a "1;" on the very last line, I had wondered if this weird FALSE statement was a poor way of forcing a return(0) of a function.  I posted here as a kind of reality-check to see if these were some kind of obscure Perl black-magic, but after hearing your thoughts, I'm beginning to accept that these lines don't do anything at all.  But they still leave me wondering as to why the original programmer left them in.   Thanks to all.

Comment: Looks like cargo cult programming to me.

Answer (score 0):

"if" logic in Perl can be constructed in couple of ways:

- the obvious one:

  ```
  if ($flag) { do_something() }
  ```
- less obvious one:

  ```
  do_something() if ($flag);
  ```

This example shows how exactly behaves that odd "FALSE if" statement - which only meaning is found when it is LAST statement in subroutine:

```
    use strict;

    use constant FALSE => 0;

    sub thisFunc {
        my $arg = shift;
        FALSE if ($arg ne "tif");
    }

    print "return val: ".thisFunc("ble")."\n";
    print "return val: ".thisFunc("tif")."\n";
```

output from running above is:

```
    return val: 0
    return val:
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding your signature + blog link unless it is relevant to the answer (which in this case, it isn't). You can use your own user profile for your bio and website link.

Comment: Note that this is undocumented behaviour because the last statement is not an expression.

Comment: @Hasturkun, very interesting as the line in question is in fact preceded by just such a 'shift' statement.  However, it is not the last statement, but is followed by some code,etc.  But your post does suggest it was made with a definite intention by the original programmer, and probably not a typo, as similar statements appear in other functions in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

It is pointless. I suspect it's suppose to be

```
return FALSE if $self->{_thisVar} ne "tif";
```

---

There is a similar construct that isn't pointless. If the loop condition has side-effects, the following isn't pointless:

```
1 while some_sub();
```

aka

```
while (some_sub()) { }
```

aka

```
while (1) {
   some_sub()
      or last;
}
```

Practical example:

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "xaabbx"; 1 while s/ab//; say'
xx
```